# Can TensorFlow be used for audio pitch detection?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm really new to TensorFlow and ML and I just want to know if TensorFlow can work with audio. I want to create such classifier that can detect pitch of loudest sound in audio signal despite of its source (human, instrument, bird, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you can use images in tensorflow by converting them to a numeric representation(bytes matrix in the case of images) , you can work with audio in tensorflow if you use a numeric representation. Hope this helps :)